# What did I wrong in the code. I am getting late response from Axios

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am trying to validate user details in submit, calling this method from submit click

```
   validateCredentials() {
        console.log('Validateuser')
         let isUserValid = false    
        axios.get('http://localhost:12345/api/Login/ValidateCredentials?UserID=abc&Password=abc')
        .then(res=>{isUserValid = response.data.Item1})
        console.log(isUserValid)
        return isUserValid
}
```

Here **isUserValid** is always **true** from API, but first time it returns false. After login Failed getting response as True
and the output

[Output console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3drve.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the server response synchronously and assign to a variable you need to use promises or async/await

In the above code you are using a asynchronous code axios call to set the value, but will not work all the time

Use the below code to perform asynchronous task synchronously

```
async validateCredentials() {
            console.log('Validateuser')
             let isUserValid = false    
             let reponse = await axios.get('http://localhost:12345/api/Login/ValidateCredentials?UserID=abc&Password=abc')
              isUserValid = respose.data.Item1 
              console.log(isUserValid)

        return isUserValid
}
```

Also when calling the function validateCredentials use await or promise to wait till the validation is set successfully

Comment: No luck. By using async, it always returning true :(

Comment: share your complete code, form where you are calling this function, that is the fix you need to give